# Docker docker-compose volumes delete sibling folders

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, ide, dockerfile

This is docker compose file looks like

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  portal:
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      - 'revcycle.portal.logger.root=C:/tomcat/logs/'
    volumes:
        - /src/main/webapp/sampleFiles:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/portal/sampleFiles:rw
    container_name: portal
    image: 'portal:latest'
```

docker-compose up is creating container successfully by when i check the content of the tomcat webapp All the other sibling folder of the sampleFiles are deleted.

Am i missing something with the volumn commands

Same happen when I use Intellji Idea docker plugin Bind mounts in Configuration

Comment: Can you add your image’s Dockerfile to the question?  What’s missing from the container, and what commands are you running to verify that?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
volumes:
  - /src/main/webapp/sampleFiles:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/portal/sampleFiles
```

as far as i know `rw` is for cases when you use drivers stuff...

and make sure that `/src/main/webapp/sampleFiles` is the host folder which have what you need in docker container. Because essentially it will be mapped into docker container. and will replace target folder.

this way siblings for `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/portal/sampleFiles` should stay intact. If no, try starting without `volumes` part and verify that you see siblings.

don't forget to do `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d` when you change anything in `docker-compose.yaml` file